# Dynamic SQL Exception Handling in SQL Server

Tags: java, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm executing the following Dynamic SQL on SQL Server 2008 via Java:

```
BEGIN TRY 
  BEGIN TRAN T1; 
  DELETE FROM [MyDatabase].[dbo].[MyTable]; 
  DECLARE @bulk_cmd nvarchar(max); 
  SET @bulk_cmd = 'BULK INSERT ... '; 
  EXEC (@bulk_cmd); 
  COMMIT TRAN T1; 
END TRY 
BEGIN CATCH 
  ROLLBACK TRAN T1;
  DECLARE @ErrorMessage NVARCHAR(4000), @ErrorSeverity INT, @ErrorState INT; 
  SELECT @ErrorMessage = ERROR_MESSAGE(), @ErrorSeverity = ERROR_SEVERITY(), @ErrorState = ERROR_STATE(); 
  RAISERROR (@ErrorMessage, @ErrorSeverity, @ErrorState);  
END CATCH;
```

If the SQL provided in `@bulk_cmd` contains an error, I can see that in SSMS, but when I execute in Java, the exception is not being caught.  The Java is pretty standard:

```
Statement stmt = null;      
try {                       
    stmt = conn.createStatement();
    stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
    logger.debug("SQL command executed.");
} catch (Exception ex) {            
    logger.debug("SQL command failed.");
    throw ex;
} finally {    
    if (stmt != null) {
        stmt.close();
    }
}
```

If I mess up the SQL (outside of the dynamic part), it will catch the syntax error. But why are the errors generated by the dynamic SQL not being caught by Java?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18471507/dynamic-sql-exception-handling-in-sql-server).

Adding `SET NOCOUNT ON;` at the beginning of the SQL fixed the issue.  Now my exceptions are being caught in Java.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to handle, you can check for

```
dbo.spGet_LastErrorMessage;
```

or checking for

```
 @@error
```

But if you are sending the command from java, why do you have bussines logic in the DDBB? Why don't you build the query using java and then execute the command as a regular SQL query?

Comment: I'm using special characters for the BULK INSERT command.  If I don't generate the command dynamically, it won't be valid syntax.

Comment: You can generate the command dinamically, but in the application side instead of DDBB side, can't you?

Comment: Yes, I tested it and it looks like that will work too.  Wasn't sure if the CHARs would translate properly between Java and SQL Server.

Comment: @Paul Apart from been a working solution, it's a better design to keep business logic in the application instead than in DDBB.